# Можно ли как то повесить на mat-slide-toggle две функции

Tags: angular, angular4, angular5, angular10

Я получил заблокирован пользователь или нет .
У меня есть 2 функции заблокировать пользователя и разблокировать пользователя.
Хочу что б при нажатии на toggle срабатывали эти функции или может есть какой то другой способ.
Что бы допустим на false было не заблокирован , а на true заблокирован.

Мой html в mat-slide-toggle принимаю заброкирован ли пользователь , что бы отобразилось на форме.

```
<table>
        <thead>
            <tr class="listColor">
                <td class="listName">User name</td>
                <td class="listEmail">User Email</td>
                <td class="listStatus">Status</td>
                <td class="listEditDelete"></td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let user of clients | async">
                <td>{{user.firstName}} {{user.lastName}}</td>
                <td>{{user.email}}</td>
                <td><mat-slide-toggle [checked]="user.isBlocked" ></mat-slide-toggle></td>
                <td>
                    <a class="listEditButton" (click)="editUser(user.id)"><img class="listEditImg" src="../../../../assets/edit.png"/></a>
                    <a class="listDeleteButton" (click)="deleteUser(user.id)"><img class="listDeleteImg" src="../../../../assets/delete.png"/></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Вот функция для блокировки

```
 blockUser(id){
    this.store$.dispatch(new BlockUser(id));
  }
```

И вот для разблокировки

```
unblockUser(id){
    this.store$.dispatch(new UnBlockUser(id));
  }
```

[image: Ошибка]

Comment: Не уверен, что правильно понял что именно вы хотите, но ответ накрапал

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<mat-slide-toggle [(ngModel)]="blockUnblock"></mat-slide-toggle>
```

ts:

```
class UserAction {    

    set blockUnblock(value: boolean) {
        this.user.isBlocked = value;
        if (value) {
            this.blockUser(user.id);
        } else {
            this.unblockUser(user.id);
        }
    }
    
    get blockUnblock(): boolean {
        return this.user.isBlocked;
    }

}
```

Comment: это бы отлично подойдет для одного юзера а у меня список

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста , а почему не работате вот такая функция                                    ```block(user: UserProfile){
    console.log(user.isBlocked);
    if (user.isBlocked === false){
      this.blockUser(this.id);
    }
    else{
      this.unblockUser(this.id);
    }
  }```

Comment: @Dmitriy потому что если ваш пользователь не заблокирован, а вы делаете вот так `user.isBlocked === false`, то это вернет true и соответствующий код блокировки не выполнится. Делайте так `if( !user.isBlocked) { ... `

Comment: Сейчас я получаю ошибку, ошибку добавил выше, в html вызываю функцию вот так (change)="block(user)"

Comment: Все я наше ошибку , я тупонул, нужно было не this.id а user.id. Спасибо вам огромное) Вы мне очень помогли))))